# ASP.NET: Redirect to User's homepage

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is this possible? i have an exit button on my web application, originally, my client request that once they click the exit button, it should CLOSE the tab or the browser itself but afaik that's impossible since the web aplication can be opened via link in an email (outlook,yahoomail etc) via  tag, so I suggested this alternative to simply just redirect to the Home (of the user, not the web app). the problem how to Redirect to *USER's* home page. TIA

Comment: IMO this is a case where it's the developer's duty to steer the client away from silly requirements. Browsers/tabs have close buttons, not the content within them... its meaningless.

Comment: unfortunately for me, thats one of the requirements that has been _signed_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (window.home){
  window.home();
}else{
  window.location='about:home';
}
```

Something like that would be my guess.

[`window.home()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.home) reference.

Comment: And just to beat any commenter to it: no I don't recommend the above (usually the visitor is pushed to a landing page on the same site), however for the purposes of the question I've done a best-guess.

Comment: should i put it inside a function to call it from my exit button server control?

Comment: its not workin in IE and FF, only in Netscape. And netscape is the least in our mind.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to detect user's existing settings for a home page. This is a security issue. You can always, however, close the browser window after the user is finished using your application.

JS: `window.close();`

Comment: i tried it and it only works for Page thats been opened by the web application via javascript (windows.open) and in IE. but in my case, the link to the web app is from the email of the client usually a link in the email, email applications could be outlook, etc.

Comment: You can simply direct a user to a static "You can now close this window." page. This is what a lot of banks do to indicate that the session is terminated after logging out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that would be advisable (even if it were possible), as users can have multiple homepages. Usually, web applications have a log-out button which would log the user out and return to the application's main page (probably showing a log-in form).

Comment: unfortunately, theres not even a login form in the web app.